# Using a distinct Root component in Angular2

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm very used to Ionic, and I recently started developping web apps with Angular2. I have an issue with the Router concept.

Let's say I want to make an app, with a login page, which redirects you to a dashboard with 3 tabs.

I Have a LoginPage component, which checks the login details and redirects to the app. How can I simply switch component in Angular 2 ?

I defined my route

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent }
];
```

And on my app.component page, I juste have a button

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
  <!--<a routerLink="/login">Heroes</a>-->
  <button (click)="login()">Change</button>
</h1>
```

trigerring this function :

```
login() {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

When I click this button, my URL is changing : http://localhost:4200/login
But my view is still my view with the button, there is no "change" like in Ionic with a `NavController.setRoot(NewComponent)`

I don't want to display my content in a `<router-outlet>`, I'd like to have distincts pages with navigation between them. Is this possible in Angular2 ?

Thank in advance for your help